# PHP/mySQL Query statements into IOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I've done research but I just can't understand something. Once I search through and select all users with the ID's of "5". How is that stored?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * ID FROM Users WHERE Username = '" . $username . "'";
```

Thanks. What I'm looking for is for these to be stored into an array which I can then use in my IOS program. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### Two things

1. Query is wrong for what you are asking for, good query will be `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 5`
2. How to get it depend of what you are using to connect to db :

**With mysql its :**

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 5";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$results = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

**With PDO its :**

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 5";
$res = $PDO->query($qry);
$results = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In the two cases the result of the query is an array you can dump with `var_dump($results);`

See PHP manual for more help:

- [MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (start with [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php))
- [Class PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (start with [the constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php))

Answer (score 0):

Well first I am not a 100% sure on this but  don't think you need to append username I think you can just use  `Where Username = '$username'"`

Second: Once you connect to your db  that statement is your query statement so you just use the query function with the correct syntax:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 5"; //is to select all the ids equaling 5
$allRows = $db->mysql_query($query );
while($res = $allRows->mysql_fetch_array()){
    $res[0]; // can now be var_dumped or whatever
       // zero is the first column in the sql row. you can replace with whatever 
       //column you are trying to access
}
```